How to orbit rotate a camera from a C++ program?
I made C++ rendering application that use one camera. The camera has 3 important members: A position(m_position), an horizontal angle(m_hAngle) and a vertical angle(m_vAngle)
The application currently  support "Fly rotation" whick look like this:
https://youtu.be/HdyoTcLq7tg
When rotation should be applied the camera horizontal and vertical angles are updated, but the position remains the same.
I want to support "Orbit rotation" where the camera position is rotated: https://youtu.be/Wq0FxFp5cu8
The C++ class look like this:
class Camera
{
public:
    void onMouseMove(const Math::Uvec2& windowSize, const Math::Vec2& mousePos);

    Math::Vec3 getCurrentTarget() const;
    Math::Vec3 getCurrentDirection() const;

    void moveForward(nbFloat32 intensity);

    // Fly mode rotation.
    void horizontalRotationFly(Math::Radian angle);
    void verticalRotationFly(Math::Radian angle);

    // Orbit mode rotation to IMPLEMENT.
    void horizontalRotationOrbit(Math::Radian angle);
    void verticalRotationOrbit(Math::Radian angle);

    Math::Mat4 getViewMatrix() const;

    // Non required code to understand question
    //....
    //
private:
    Math::Vec3 m_up = Math::Vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    Math::Vec3 m_position;
    Math::Radian m_hAngle;
    Math::Radian m_vAngle;

    bool m_mousePressed;
};

inline Math::Vec3 Camera::getCurrentTarget() const
{
    return m_position + getCurrentDirection();
}

inline Math::Vec3 Camera::getCurrentDirection() const
{
    // Dont remember where that code is from but it works.
    return glm::normalize(
        Math::Vec3(
            std::cosf(-m_hAngle.getValue()),
            std::tanf(m_vAngle.getValue()),
            std::sin(-m_hAngle.getValue())
        )
    );
}

inline void Camera::moveForward(nbFloat32 intensity)
{
    const Math::Vec3 direction = getCurrentDirection();
    m_position += (direction * intensity);
}


inline Math::Mat4 Camera::getViewMatrix() const
{
    return glm::lookAt(m_position, getCurrentTarget(), m_up);
}

When mouse is dragged I perform the rotation
void Camera::onMouseMove(const Math::Uvec2& windowSize, const Math::Vec2& mousePos)
{
    if (!m_mousePressed)
        return;

    Math::Vec2 deltaRatio = mousePos - m_currentMousePosition;
    deltaRatio.x /= (nbFloat32)windowSize.x;
    deltaRatio.y /= (nbFloat32)windowSize.y;

    m_currentMousePosition = mousePos;

    static const float rotationSensibility = 2.40f;
    static const bool flyRotation = true;

    if (flyRotation)
    {
        horizontalRotationFly(Math::Radian(-deltaRatio.x * rotationSensibility));
        verticalRotationFly(Math::Radian(-deltaRatio.y * rotationSensibility));
    }
    else
    {
        // HERE to implement
        horizontalRotationOrbit(Math::Radian(-deltaRatio.x * rotationSensibility));
        verticalRotationOrbit(Math::Radian(-deltaRatio.y * rotationSensibility));
    }
}

The FLY rotation functions are implemented this this:
inline void Camera::horizontalRotationFly(Math::Radian angle)
{
    m_hAngle += angle;
}

inline void Camera::verticalRotationFly(Math::Radian angle)
{
    m_vAngle += angle;
}

Now I need to implement the ORBIT ones:
inline void Camera::horizontalRotationOrbit(Math::Radian angle)
{
    //TODO.
}

inline void Camera::verticalRotationOrbit(Math::Radian angle)
{
    //TODO.
}

Thanks for helping!

What is it you want your camera to orbit around?  The scene origin?  The unit vector you're using to construct the at parameter to lookat?  A point in screen space?  All of those have valid, but different answers.

Hello Jherico,
Thank you very much for helping. Lets say i want to rotate camera around a given point P(Px, Py, Pz)

I use a right handed coordinate system:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb324490%28v=vs.85%29

I have a code for a 'uv camera': https://github.com/sjhalayka/opengl1_stlview

In order to orbit the camera around a specific point, you need to have that point available to the function that's doing the orbiting.  So lets have the signatures reflect that...
inline void Camera::horizontalRotationOrbit(const Math::Vec3 & center, Math::Radian angle)

You want to orbit the point relative to the center of rotation
    auto v = m_position - center;

Now you need to construct a rotation matrix for the angle.  I don't know what your Math API looks like, but you'll probably want something like
    static const auto UP = Math::Vec3{0, 0, -1};
    auto m = Math::rotate(Math::Mat4{}, angle, UP);

Most matrix math libraries will include a function like this to build a rotation matrix out of an axis and an angle.
Now you want to actually apply the rotation
    v = m * v;

And then you want to put it back, relative to the origin, and store the new value.
    m_position = v + center;
 

Finally, you want to alter the camera direction to account for the rotation
    m_hAngle -= angle;

This approach should work for horizontal orbiting (yaw around the point), but the vertical orbiting is slightly more complex, because your rotation isn't about a cardinal direction, like the up vector in the previous code.  Instead you need to use m_hAngle to calculate the axis around which to pitch.  Our starting axis is the X axis, around which you normally pitch.
    static const auto LEFT = Math::Vec3{1, 0, 0};

We want to make a new axis that rotates that by m_hAngle.  The result should still be a unit vector in the XZ plane, and it should be orthogonal to the required pitch direction.
    auto axis = Math::rotate(Math::Mat4{}, m_hAngle, UP) * LEFT;

We can use this axis to build the final rotation matrix
    auto m = Math::rotate(Math::Mat4{}, angle, axis);

The rest of the function works the same, rotating your point around m and subtracting the angle value from m_vAngle when you're done.

Thank you! I got the horizontal rotation working. However vertical rotation doesnt. I get this: https://youtu.be/znBxppvT5sk
Look at the mouse cursor. When i drag rotation does not follow properly. I disabled horizontal rotation for this test.
Please can you clarify "The rest of the function works the same, rotating your point around m and subtracting the angle value from m_vAngle when you're done." ? Here the current code: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/j6db2s1vjs675xe5t9b30/Camera.cpp?rlkey=1jbs86613yxhqmtl4sb3kezqx&st=kpk2ohea&dl=0
